# Imprimir matrizes com line break

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Quero imprimir as diversas variáveis de uma `List`. Estou tentando usando `foreach` mas não tem funcionado. As variáveis são escritas umas sobre as outras ao invés de uma quebra de linha. Vejam meu código que consta no evento **printPage**:

```
        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;

        var Fonte = new Font("Arial", 18);

        Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];

        foreach (var cli in cliente.Produtos)
        {
            string impressao = string.Format("Produto: {0}", cli.NomeProduto);

            e.Graphics.MeasureString(impressao, Fonte, e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic, out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(impressao, Fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            impressao = impressao.Substring(charactersOnPage);

            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
```

Eu preciso ter como saída na visualização da impressão algo como:

```
Produto: Carro
Produto: Bicicleta
```

Com este meu código, os produtos ficam todos embaralhados um em cima do outro.

É a primeira vez que estou estudando impressão.

Comment: Não conheço esta engine de impressão, mas acredito que falte uma quebra de linha ou algo assim

Comment: Você já tentou usar "\n" ou System.Environment.NewLine para quebrar a linha onde desejado?
Senão tentou, faça um teste. Exemplo, caso você desejasse quebrar a linha depois do nome do produto: string impressao = string.Format("Produto: {0}", cli.NomeProduto) + "\n";

Comment: @Renan sim, tentei usando \n mas não funcionou. O System.Environment.NewLine eu desconhecia, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: @Caputo Sim, após tentar com \n sem sucesso vim aqui pra tentar descobrir outros métodos para realizar essa quebra de linha.

Comment: @Renan Environment.NewLine também não causa nenhum efeito.

Comment: @Omni tentei de todas as formas que você expôs, mas nenhuma funcionou. As strings insistem em ficar embaralhadas uma em cima da outra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema ocorre devido a este pedaço de código:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(impressao, Fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

Como está sempre a passar o mesmo valor de `e.MarginBounds` para `DrawString`, as diversas `strings` estão a ser desenhadas todas dentro do mesmo rectângulo.

Uma forma de resolver o seu problema seria criar o texto todo antes de mandar desenhar:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var cli in cliente.Produtos)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("Produto: {0}\n", cli.NomeProduto);
}

string stringFinal = sb.ToString();

e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringFinal, Fonte, e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic, out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

e.Graphics.DrawString(stringFinal, Fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

e.HasMorePages = false;
```

Comment: Entendi sua lógica! Era exatamente essa a raiz do problema! Muito obrigado, grande abraço! :)